# Google Fonts not loading properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-webfonts

Could someone check this out for me?

The defined behaviour in every browser except Firefox is that a web-font will be invisible until loaded (but the space saved).

In Chrome and IE9 that I can test on, you can see a weird bug, IE9 shows it off the best.

When the page loads, the header text is displayed, then its turned invisible for a second as the web font is loaded.

Strangely, I believe the font that is first flashed is the web font.

I've found its a bit hard to see in Chrome because of the refresh, whereas on IE9 the background doesn't refresh so you can see the text go wacky really easy.

Here is a link to the demo site I'm working on :-----

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Web fonts always work that way in my experience.

Comment: checked with firebug everything is fine

Comment: I figured out the problem. The javascript version produces the error. I tried using the CSS call for the fonts and the issue is gone (or at least reduced quite a bit).

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=BenchNine' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

use this in css font-family: 'BenchNine', sans-serif;
```

easy